# Index of a permutation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, permutation, representation

I was recently reading about Lehmer codes and how they can be used to map an *index* to a *permutation* corresponding to that *index* and realized they can be quite useful to quickly generate a permutation. Does anyone know how can this be done using an algorithm, and also what are the limits of such a method, I suppose we can't go above index = 1.7977e+308, but still seems quite an interesting method.

So basically lets say we have

```
perm
  1   0 0 0
  2   0 0 1
  3   0 0 2
  4   0 1 0
  5   0 1 1
  6   0 1 2
     ...
```

We should be able to deduce that the index of [ 0 1 0 ] is 4, 
or that the index 6 corresponds to [ 0 1 2 ]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that what you are describing here are not permutations...

Comment: Indeed you are right. I just wanted to write a quick example to help illustrate better what I had in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vector for each index is the base 3 representation of the index (minus one)
the functions `dec2base` and `base2dec` can be used for this with a little fiddling to get the sting outputs to the required format

### index to vector

```
index=4; % input index
n=3;     % length of vector 

vec=str2num([dec2base(index-1,3,n)].').'
vec=

     0     1     0
```

### vector to index

```
vec=[0,1,2]; % input vector
vecstr=strcat(['' vec(:)+'0'].');
index=base2dec(vecstr,3)+1

index =

     6
```

Comment: Which programming language is above code? can some one write the same in C program please.